# Append array to atribute of another array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm learning Javascript and I'm stuck in a doubt with the joining of two arrays of objects through an ID, I can join the two, but the result is not what I expect.

So, I have these two object arrays:

```
"product": [
        {
            "id": "1000",
            "code": "f230fh0g3",
            "name": "Bamboo Watch",
            "description": "Product Description",
            "image": "bamboo-watch.jpg",
            "price": 65,
            "category": "Accessories",
            "quantity": 24,
         }
]

"orders": [            
       {                
            "id": "1000",             
            "productID": "f230fh0g3",           
            "date": "2020-09-13",
            "amount": 65,
            "quantity": 1,
       },
       {                
            "id": "1000",             
            "productID": "f230fh0g3",           
            "date": "2020-09-13",
            "amount": 65,
            "quantity": 1,
       },
]
```

and I want to join both by key (id) to get one array like this one:

```
"product": [
        {
            "id": "1000",
            "code": "f230fh0g3",
            "name": "Bamboo Watch",
            "description": "Product Description",
            "image": "bamboo-watch.jpg",
            "price": 65,
            "category": "Accessories",
            "quantity": 24,
            "orders": [
                {
                    "id": "1000",
                    "productCode": "f230fh0g3",
                    "date": "2020-09-13",
                    "amount": 65,
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "customer": "David James",
                    "status": "PENDING"
                },
                {
                    "id": "1001",
                    "productCode": "f230fh0g3",
                    "date": "2020-05-14",
                    "amount": 130,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "customer": "Leon Rodrigues",
                    "status": "DELIVERED"
                },
              ]
    },
    {
         "id": "1001",
         "..."
         "orders": [
               {
                     "id": "1001",
                     "..."
               }
           ]
    }]
```

Is it possible to map these arrays in this way?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use `.map()` and `.filter()` together. Assuming you have products in `product` variable and orders in `order` variable, you can compute your combined list like this:

```js
const result = products.map(
    product => ({
        ...product,
        orders: orders.filter(
            ({ productID }) => productID === product.id
        )
    })
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much Robo Robok, your solution worked perfect !!!